# Meteor/Autoform - Issue with before:update

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform

I inserted a before update hook but receive this error message?

Uncaught Error: before.update hook must return an object

Code:

```
before: {
update: function(doc, template) {
doc.step="aaa";

    return doc;

  }
}
```

I do the same thing with before:insert and it is working fine?
Even if i delete "doc.step="aaa" it isn't working?

What I'm doing wrong?